# Перемещение текста с дочернего окна на Главное окно

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside6

Нужна помощь в решении следующей задачи. Есть два окна:

- первоое - главное, где есть `listWidget_users`,
- второе окно, где водится логин и пароль.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы с дочернего (**`2`**) окна передать текст с поля логин после нажатия на кнопку 'ДОБАВИТЬ' в главное (**`1`**) окно в `listWidget_users`.

В коде используется библиотека *PySide6*. Нужна помощь специалиста, который поможет сделать данные действия с библиотекой *PySide6*

**main.py**:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

from Viwe.loginWindow import LoginWindow
from Viwe.ui_main_window import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.btn_user.clicked.connect(self.open_zavdannia)

    def open_zavdannia(self):
        self.window2 = LoginWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**ui_main_window.py**:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QLayout,
    QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QMainWindow, QPlainTextEdit,
    QProgressBar, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem,
    QVBoxLayout, QWidget)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(969, 574)
        MainWindow.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.Russian, QLocale.Russia))
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.main_frame = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.main_frame.setObjectName(u"main_frame")
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.main_frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.left_frame = QFrame(self.main_frame)
        self.left_frame.setObjectName(u"left_frame")
        self.left_frame.setMaximumSize(QSize(250, 16777215))
        self.left_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.left_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QVBoxLayout(self.left_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.users_frame = QFrame(self.left_frame)
        self.users_frame.setObjectName(u"users_frame")
        self.users_frame.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 0))
        self.users_frame.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.users_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.users_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QVBoxLayout(self.users_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_8")
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(2, 0, 2, 0)
        self.listWidget_users = QListWidget(self.users_frame)
        self.listWidget_users.setObjectName(u"listWidget_users")

        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.listWidget_users)


        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.users_frame)

        self.buttom_frame = QFrame(self.left_frame)
        self.buttom_frame.setObjectName(u"buttom_frame")
        self.buttom_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.buttom_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self.buttom_frame)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.add_frame = QFrame(self.buttom_frame)
        self.add_frame.setObjectName(u"add_frame")
        self.add_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.add_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QVBoxLayout(self.add_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 9, 9, 9)
        self.btn_user = QPushButton(self.add_frame)
        self.btn_user.setObjectName(u"btn_user")

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_user)


        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.add_frame)

        self.clear_frame = QFrame(self.buttom_frame)
        self.clear_frame.setObjectName(u"clear_frame")
        self.clear_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.clear_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.clear_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(9, 9, 0, 9)
        self.btn_clear = QPushButton(self.clear_frame)
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName(u"btn_clear")

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_clear)


        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.clear_frame)


        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.buttom_frame)


        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.left_frame)

        self.midle_frame = QFrame(self.main_frame)
        self.midle_frame.setObjectName(u"midle_frame")
        self.midle_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.midle_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.midle_frame)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.log_frame = QFrame(self.midle_frame)
        self.log_frame.setObjectName(u"log_frame")
        self.log_frame.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.log_frame.setSizeIncrement(QSize(0, 0))
        self.log_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.log_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QVBoxLayout(self.log_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(2, 0, 2, 2)
        self.plainTextEdit_log = QPlainTextEdit(self.log_frame)
        self.plainTextEdit_log.setObjectName(u"plainTextEdit_log")
        self.plainTextEdit_log.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))

        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit_log)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.log_frame)

        self.bar_frame = QFrame(self.midle_frame)
        self.bar_frame.setObjectName(u"bar_frame")
        self.bar_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.bar_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QVBoxLayout(self.bar_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_6")
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(20, 9, 10, 9)
        self.progressBar = QProgressBar(self.bar_frame)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName(u"progressBar")
        self.progressBar.setValue(24)

        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.bar_frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.midle_frame)

        self.riate_frame = QFrame(self.main_frame)
        self.riate_frame.setObjectName(u"riate_frame")
        self.riate_frame.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.riate_frame.setSizeIncrement(QSize(0, 0))
        self.riate_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.riate_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QVBoxLayout(self.riate_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_7")
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(10, 9, 10, 9)
        self.btn_start_scraping = QPushButton(self.riate_frame)
        self.btn_start_scraping.setObjectName(u"btn_start_scraping")

        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.btn_start_scraping)

        self.btn_open_log = QPushButton(self.riate_frame)
        self.btn_open_log.setObjectName(u"btn_open_log")
        self.btn_open_log.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.Russian, QLocale.Russia))

        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.btn_open_log)

        self.verticalSpacer_2 = QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.verticalLayout_7.addItem(self.verticalSpacer_2)


        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.riate_frame)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.main_frame)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.btn_user.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0414\u043e\u0431\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.btn_clear.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0447\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.plainTextEdit_log.setPlainText("")
        self.btn_start_scraping.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0417\u0430\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0442\u044c \u043f\u0430\u0440\u0441\u0438\u043d\u0433", None))
        self.btn_open_log.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0442\u043a\u0440\u044b\u0442\u044c \u043b\u043e\u0433", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

**LoginWindow.py**:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

from Viwe.ui_login_window import Ui_LoginWindow

class LoginWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_LoginWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.btn_login.clicked.connect(self.addUser)

        self.show()

    def addUser(self):
        login = self.ui.lineEdit_login.text()
        passwd = self.ui.lineEdit_passwd.text()

        self.close()
```

**ui_login_window.py**:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
    QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QSizePolicy,
    QVBoxLayout, QWidget)

class Ui_LoginWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, LoginWindow):
        if not LoginWindow.objectName():
            LoginWindow.setObjectName(u"LoginWindow")
        LoginWindow.resize(338, 160)
        LoginWindow.setMinimumSize(QSize(338, 160))
        LoginWindow.setMaximumSize(QSize(338, 160))
        self.main_login = QWidget(LoginWindow)
        self.main_login.setObjectName(u"main_login")
        self.main_login.setMinimumSize(QSize(338, 160))
        self.main_login.setMaximumSize(QSize(338, 160))
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.main_login)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.frame_login_passwd = QFrame(self.main_login)
        self.frame_login_passwd.setObjectName(u"frame_login_passwd")
        self.frame_login_passwd.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_login_passwd.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_login_passwd)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.frame_6 = QFrame(self.frame_login_passwd)
        self.frame_6.setObjectName(u"frame_6")
        self.frame_6.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_6.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_6)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.frame_login = QFrame(self.frame_6)
        self.frame_login.setObjectName(u"frame_login")
        self.frame_login.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_login.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_login)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setSpacing(20)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(9, 0, 9, 0)
        self.label_login = QLabel(self.frame_login)
        self.label_login.setObjectName(u"label_login")

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_login)

        self.lineEdit_login = QLineEdit(self.frame_login)
        self.lineEdit_login.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_login")
        self.lineEdit_login.setClearButtonEnabled(True)

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_login)


        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_login)

        self.frame_passwd = QFrame(self.frame_6)
        self.frame_passwd.setObjectName(u"frame_passwd")
        self.frame_passwd.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_passwd.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_passwd)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(12)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(-1, 0, -1, 0)
        self.label_passwd = QLabel(self.frame_passwd)
        self.label_passwd.setObjectName(u"label_passwd")

        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_passwd)

        self.lineEdit_passwd = QLineEdit(self.frame_passwd)
        self.lineEdit_passwd.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_passwd")
        self.lineEdit_passwd.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit_passwd.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit_passwd.setClearButtonEnabled(True)

        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit_passwd)


        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_passwd)


        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_6)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_login_passwd)

        self.frame_btn = QFrame(self.main_login)
        self.frame_btn.setObjectName(u"frame_btn")
        self.frame_btn.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_btn.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_btn)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.frame_add = QFrame(self.frame_btn)
        self.frame_add.setObjectName(u"frame_add")
        self.frame_add.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_add.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_add)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(9, 0, 9, 0)
        self.btn_login = QPushButton(self.frame_add)
        self.btn_login.setObjectName(u"btn_login")

        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_login)


        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_add)

        self.frame_clear = QFrame(self.frame_btn)
        self.frame_clear.setObjectName(u"frame_clear")
        self.frame_clear.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_clear.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_clear)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(-1, 0, -1, 0)
        self.btn_clear = QPushButton(self.frame_clear)
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName(u"btn_clear")

        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.btn_clear)


        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_clear)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_btn)

        LoginWindow.setCentralWidget(self.main_login)

        self.retranslateUi(LoginWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(LoginWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, LoginWindow):
        LoginWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"Log In", None))
        self.label_login.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u041b\u043e\u0433\u0438\u043d", None))
        self.label_passwd.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u041f\u0430\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044c", None))
        self.btn_login.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u0414\u043e\u0431\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.btn_clear.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u041e\u0447\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании экземпляра второго окна передайте ссылку на первое окно:

```
self.window2 = LoginWindow(self)
#                          ^^^^
```

и в методе `addUser()` модуля **loginWindow.py**:

```
self.parent.ui.listWidget_users.addItem(login)
```

---

**main.py**

```
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from loginWindow import LoginWindow

#from Viwe.ui_main_window import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(969, 574)
        MainWindow.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.Russian, QLocale.Russia))
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.main_frame = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.main_frame.setObjectName(u"main_frame")
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.main_frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.left_frame = QFrame(self.main_frame)
        self.left_frame.setObjectName(u"left_frame")
        self.left_frame.setMaximumSize(QSize(250, 16777215))
        self.left_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.left_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QVBoxLayout(self.left_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.users_frame = QFrame(self.left_frame)
        self.users_frame.setObjectName(u"users_frame")
        self.users_frame.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 0))
        self.users_frame.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.users_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.users_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QVBoxLayout(self.users_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_8")
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(2, 0, 2, 0)
        self.listWidget_users = QListWidget(self.users_frame)
        self.listWidget_users.setObjectName(u"listWidget_users")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.listWidget_users)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.users_frame)

        self.buttom_frame = QFrame(self.left_frame)
        self.buttom_frame.setObjectName(u"buttom_frame")
        self.buttom_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.buttom_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self.buttom_frame)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.add_frame = QFrame(self.buttom_frame)
        self.add_frame.setObjectName(u"add_frame")
        self.add_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.add_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QVBoxLayout(self.add_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 9, 9, 9)
        self.btn_user = QPushButton(self.add_frame)
        self.btn_user.setObjectName(u"btn_user")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_user)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.add_frame)

        self.clear_frame = QFrame(self.buttom_frame)
        self.clear_frame.setObjectName(u"clear_frame")
        self.clear_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.clear_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.clear_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(9, 9, 0, 9)
        self.btn_clear = QPushButton(self.clear_frame)
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName(u"btn_clear")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_clear)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.clear_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.buttom_frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.left_frame)

        self.midle_frame = QFrame(self.main_frame)
        self.midle_frame.setObjectName(u"midle_frame")
        self.midle_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.midle_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.midle_frame)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.log_frame = QFrame(self.midle_frame)
        self.log_frame.setObjectName(u"log_frame")
        self.log_frame.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.log_frame.setSizeIncrement(QSize(0, 0))
        self.log_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.log_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QVBoxLayout(self.log_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(2, 0, 2, 2)
        self.plainTextEdit_log = QPlainTextEdit(self.log_frame)
        self.plainTextEdit_log.setObjectName(u"plainTextEdit_log")
        self.plainTextEdit_log.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit_log)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.log_frame)

        self.bar_frame = QFrame(self.midle_frame)
        self.bar_frame.setObjectName(u"bar_frame")
        self.bar_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.bar_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QVBoxLayout(self.bar_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_6")
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(20, 9, 10, 9)
        self.progressBar = QProgressBar(self.bar_frame)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName(u"progressBar")
        self.progressBar.setValue(24)
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.bar_frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.midle_frame)

        self.riate_frame = QFrame(self.main_frame)
        self.riate_frame.setObjectName(u"riate_frame")
        self.riate_frame.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.riate_frame.setSizeIncrement(QSize(0, 0))
        self.riate_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.riate_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QVBoxLayout(self.riate_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_7")
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(10, 9, 10, 9)
        self.btn_start_scraping = QPushButton(self.riate_frame)
        self.btn_start_scraping.setObjectName(u"btn_start_scraping")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.btn_start_scraping)

        self.btn_open_log = QPushButton(self.riate_frame)
        self.btn_open_log.setObjectName(u"btn_open_log")
        self.btn_open_log.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.Russian, QLocale.Russia))
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.btn_open_log)
        self.verticalSpacer_2 = QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addItem(self.verticalSpacer_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.riate_frame)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.main_frame)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.btn_user.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0414\u043e\u0431\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.btn_clear.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0447\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.plainTextEdit_log.setPlainText("")
        self.btn_start_scraping.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0417\u0430\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0442\u044c \u043f\u0430\u0440\u0441\u0438\u043d\u0433", None))
        self.btn_open_log.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0442\u043a\u0440\u044b\u0442\u044c \u043b\u043e\u0433", None))
    # retranslateUi
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.btn_user.clicked.connect(self.open_zavdannia)
        
        self.ui.listWidget_users.itemClicked.connect(self.item_clicked)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def item_clicked(self, item):
        QMessageBox.information(
            self, 
            "ListWidget", 
            f"You clicked: {item.text()}"
        )
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def open_zavdannia(self):
        self.window2 = LoginWindow(self)                           # !!! +++ (self) 
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**loginWindow.py**

```
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from Viwe.ui_login_window import Ui_LoginWindow
class Ui_LoginWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, LoginWindow):
        if not LoginWindow.objectName():
            LoginWindow.setObjectName(u"LoginWindow")
        LoginWindow.resize(338, 160)
        LoginWindow.setMinimumSize(QSize(338, 160))
        LoginWindow.setMaximumSize(QSize(338, 160))
        self.main_login = QWidget(LoginWindow)
        self.main_login.setObjectName(u"main_login")
        self.main_login.setMinimumSize(QSize(338, 160))
        self.main_login.setMaximumSize(QSize(338, 160))
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.main_login)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.frame_login_passwd = QFrame(self.main_login)
        self.frame_login_passwd.setObjectName(u"frame_login_passwd")
        self.frame_login_passwd.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_login_passwd.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_login_passwd)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.frame_6 = QFrame(self.frame_login_passwd)
        self.frame_6.setObjectName(u"frame_6")
        self.frame_6.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_6.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_6)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.frame_login = QFrame(self.frame_6)
        self.frame_login.setObjectName(u"frame_login")
        self.frame_login.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_login.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_login)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setSpacing(20)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(9, 0, 9, 0)
        self.label_login = QLabel(self.frame_login)
        self.label_login.setObjectName(u"label_login")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_login)

        self.lineEdit_login = QLineEdit(self.frame_login)
        self.lineEdit_login.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_login")
        self.lineEdit_login.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_login)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_login)

        self.frame_passwd = QFrame(self.frame_6)
        self.frame_passwd.setObjectName(u"frame_passwd")
        self.frame_passwd.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_passwd.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_passwd)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(12)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(-1, 0, -1, 0)
        self.label_passwd = QLabel(self.frame_passwd)
        self.label_passwd.setObjectName(u"label_passwd")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_passwd)

        self.lineEdit_passwd = QLineEdit(self.frame_passwd)
        self.lineEdit_passwd.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_passwd")
        self.lineEdit_passwd.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit_passwd.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit_passwd.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit_passwd)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_passwd)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_6)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_login_passwd)

        self.frame_btn = QFrame(self.main_login)
        self.frame_btn.setObjectName(u"frame_btn")
        self.frame_btn.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_btn.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_btn)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.frame_add = QFrame(self.frame_btn)
        self.frame_add.setObjectName(u"frame_add")
        self.frame_add.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_add.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_add)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(9, 0, 9, 0)
        self.btn_login = QPushButton(self.frame_add)
        self.btn_login.setObjectName(u"btn_login")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_login)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_add)

        self.frame_clear = QFrame(self.frame_btn)
        self.frame_clear.setObjectName(u"frame_clear")
        self.frame_clear.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_clear.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_clear)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(-1, 0, -1, 0)
        self.btn_clear = QPushButton(self.frame_clear)
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName(u"btn_clear")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.btn_clear)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_clear)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_btn)
        LoginWindow.setCentralWidget(self.main_login)

        self.retranslateUi(LoginWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(LoginWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, LoginWindow):
        LoginWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"Log In", None))
        self.label_login.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u041b\u043e\u0433\u0438\u043d", None))
        self.label_passwd.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u041f\u0430\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044c", None))
        self.btn_login.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u0414\u043e\u0431\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.btn_clear.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("LoginWindow", u"\u041e\u0447\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))


class LoginWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_LoginWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.parent = parent                                         # !!! +++

        self.ui.btn_login.clicked.connect(self.addUser)

        self.show()

    def addUser(self):
        login = self.ui.lineEdit_login.text()
        passwd = self.ui.lineEdit_passwd.text()

        self.parent.ui.listWidget_users.addItem(login)              # !!! +++

        self.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо тебе огромное за помощь)) я очень сильно тебе благодарен

Comment: @ВладиславЛинский пожалуйста. Удачи ВАМ.